# Non-resident alien with partnership income

Tags: united-states, income-tax, non-resident, massachusetts

I am a non-resident alien with partnership income, and MA state tax has been withheld. I have never been in MA ever.

Looking at the MA state non-resident income tax form, it asks to report income "as if I were a MA resident". Does that include my foreign income? Note that my US income tax reported on the federal tax return is just $800 of dividend income, my foreign-source income is excluded there. Thanks!